# How to represent dual-cell format in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've been having this problem for awhile now.

Anyways, given this code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><img src="" /></td>
    <td valign="middle">Text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This renders a format with an image to the left, and some vertically centered text to the right of it. This works because then I can have multi-line text, and still have the image positioned "nicely".

Now, ideally, tables should only be used for tabular data, yes? So how can I represent this in CSS?

I'm thinking `<div>` tags? But I encapsulate the entire bit in a `<p>` box with style="display: table; border: 1px solid black;", and I'm afraid relative positioned divs might end up jutting out of the box, necessitating tweaking, which I am loathe to do in CSS...

Help!

Comment: Do you have to concern yourself with variable height?
In other words, will either <td><img src="" /></td> or <td valign="middle">Text</td> change heights unpredictably, either by changing the image, or by adding Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<img src="..." />
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
 width: 200px;
}

#container img, #container img{
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: Float... of course! Wow, I'm rusty with my CSS.

In fact, I hadn't even realized I'd transitioned back into tabular formatting until recently... old habits die hard, I guess.

Thanks again.

Comment: And where's the vertical-align? :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle;">
 <img style="float:left;" src="" alt="" />
 <p>Your text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: vertical-align is not the equivalent of the HTML valign. It aligns inline elements relative to other inline elements, not text within block elements.

Comment: Aren't <img> inline-block elements?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter what tags you are using (especially after a css reset). you just need to set the wrapper tag `display: table;` and the nested cell tags to `display: table-cell;` after that you can use the `vertical-align` you also may need put even more tags around your content to recreate a true table, whit table rows.